# Excel VBA ordering of records

Tags: excel, vba

I have below data

```
 Empid       Empname   salary   Company   location   status

    x1         Phil       50      IBM        us
    x2         Karl       30      IBM        us
    x3         Steve      20      IBM        us
    x4         jacob      70      Oracle     uk
    x5         jason      30      Oracle     uk
    x6         stuart     50      Oracle     uk
    zz         jay        150      Oracle    uk
   x10         Steve1     20      IBM        ind
    x9         Steve2     20      IBM        nj
    xx         Jhon      100      IBM        us
```

I have to write one VB macro to separate records based on company and location. So I will get below two set of records

**First Set**

```
Empid     Empname   salary   company    Location  status
    xx        Jhon             100      IBM           us   
    x1        Phil             50       IBM          us
    x2        Karl             30       IBM         us
    x3        Steve            20       IBM         us
```

**Second set**

```
   Empid     Empname   salary   company  Location  status
    x4        jacob      70       Oracle    uk
    x5        jason      30       Oracle    uk
    x6        stuart     50       Oracle    uk
    zz        jay       150       Oracle    uk
```

**How below code works:**
Bsed on company and location first it will get different sets of data.After that it will filter out based on master records XX or zz.if any of the master record there in that set then it will consider whole set.Finally in each set based on master record quantity comparing all other child records quantity.if it matches then i am copying to new sheet.

Below code working fine ,if master records xx,zz coming in the order following to the child records.If i place last record in the sheet "xx         Jhon      100      IBM        us " in first place.It is working very well.Otherwise it is not working.

VBA gurus.Any help on this appreciated.

Code iam trying

```
Sub tester()

    Const COL_EID As Integer = 1
    Const COL_comp As Integer = 4
    Const COL_loc As Integer = 5
    Const COL_sal As Integer = 3
    Const COL_S As Integer = 6
    Const VAL_DIFF As String = "XXdifferentXX"

    Dim d As Object, sKey As String, sKey1 As String, id As String
    Dim rw As Range, opt As String, rngData As Range
    Dim rngCopy As Range, goodId As Boolean, goodId1 As Boolean
    Dim FirstPass As Boolean, arr, arr1

    Dim sal As Integer
    Dim colsal As Integer
    Dim mastersal As Integer
    Dim status As Boolean
    Dim status1 As Boolean

        With Sheet1.Range("A1")
            Set rngData = .CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize( _
                             .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1)
        End With
        Set rngCopy = Sheet2.Range("A1")
         FirstPass = True
        SecondPass = False
      status = False
       Set a = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

        Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")


    redo:

        For Each rw In rngData.Rows

            sKey = rw.Cells(COL_comp).Value & "<>" & _
                   rw.Cells(COL_loc).Value
            sKey1 = rw.Cells(COL_comp).Value & "<>" & _
                   rw.Cells(COL_loc).Value
            colsal = rw.Cells(COL_sal).Value
            If FirstPass Then
              id = rw.Cells(COL_EID).Value
              goodId = (id = "xx" Or id = "zz")

              If d.exists(sKey) Then
                  arr = d(sKey) 'can't modify the array in situ...

                  If goodId Then arr(0) = True
                  d(sKey) = arr 'return [modified] array

              Else
                  d.Add sKey, Array(goodId)
            End If
            End If

            If SecondPass Then
              id = rw.Cells(COL_EID).Value
              goodId1 = (id = "xx" Or id = "zz")

             If d(sKey)(0) = True Then
             If goodId1 Then mastersal = rw.Cells(COL_sal).Value
             If a.exists(sKey1) Then
                  arr1 = a(sKey1) 'can't modify the array in situ...

                  If goodId1 = False Then sal = sal + colsal
                   If mastersal = sal Then arr1(0) = True



                  'If goodId1 Then arr1(0) = True
                  a(sKey1) = arr1 'return [modified] array

              Else
                  a.Add sKey1, Array(status)
                  sal = 0
                   If goodId1 = False Then sal = sal + colsal
            End If

            End If
            End If

             If FirstPass = False And SecondPass = False Then
            If d(sKey)(0) = True Then
              If a(sKey1)(0) = True Then
                  rw.Copy rngCopy
                  Set rngCopy = rngCopy.Offset(1, 0)
             End If
            End If
            End If


        Next rw
        If SecondPass Then
            SecondPass = False
            GoTo redo
        End If
        If FirstPass Then
            FirstPass = False
            SecondPass = True
            colsal = 0
            GoTo redo
        End If

    End Sub
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use class modules.  It's a little more work up front, but much easier to read and maintain.  First, insert a Class Module into your project and name it CEmployee.  This code goes in CEmployee

```
Option Explicit

Private mlEmployeeID As Long
Private msEmpid As String
Private msEmpName As String
Private mdSalary As Double
Private msCompany As String
Private msLocation As String

Private Const msDELIM As String = "|"

Public Property Get Location() As String: Location = msLocation: End Property
Public Property Let Location(ByVal sLocation As String): msLocation = sLocation: End Property
Public Property Get Company() As String: Company = msCompany: End Property
Public Property Let Company(ByVal sCompany As String): msCompany = sCompany: End Property
Public Property Get Salary() As Double: Salary = mdSalary: End Property
Public Property Let Salary(ByVal dSalary As Double): mdSalary = dSalary: End Property
Public Property Get EmpName() As String: EmpName = msEmpName: End Property
Public Property Let EmpName(ByVal sEmpName As String): msEmpName = sEmpName: End Property
Public Property Get Empid() As String: Empid = msEmpid: End Property
Public Property Let Empid(ByVal sEmpid As String): msEmpid = sEmpid: End Property
Public Property Get EmployeeID() As Long: EmployeeID = mlEmployeeID: End Property
Public Property Let EmployeeID(ByVal lEmployeeID As Long): mlEmployeeID = lEmployeeID: End Property

Public Property Get CompLoc() As String

    CompLoc = Me.Company & msDELIM & Me.Location

End Property

Public Property Get IsMaster() As Boolean

    IsMaster = Me.Empid = String(2, Left$(Me.Empid, 1))

End Property
```

Next, insert another Class Module and name in CEmployees (plural).  You'll have to modify this module as shown at http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/07/04/custom-collection-class/ to be able to use For Each to loop through the object.  The code for CEmployees is

```
Option Explicit

Private mcolEmployees As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mcolEmployees = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set mcolEmployees = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = mcolEmployees.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Public Sub Add(clsEmployee As CEmployee)
    If clsEmployee.EmployeeID = 0 Then
        clsEmployee.EmployeeID = Me.Count + 1
    End If

    mcolEmployees.Add clsEmployee, CStr(clsEmployee.EmployeeID)
End Sub

Public Property Get Employee(vItem As Variant) As CEmployee
    Set Employee = mcolEmployees.Item(vItem)
End Property

Public Property Get Count() As Long
    Count = mcolEmployees.Count
End Property

Public Sub FillFromRange(rRng As Range)

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim clsEmployee As CEmployee

    For Each rCell In rRng.Columns(1).Cells
        Set clsEmployee = New CEmployee
        With clsEmployee
            .Empid = rCell.Value
            .EmpName = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Salary = rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Company = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Location = rCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        End With
        Me.Add clsEmployee
    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Property Get UniqueCompLoc() As Collection

    Dim colReturn As Collection
    Dim clsEmployee As CEmployee

    Set colReturn = New Collection

    For Each clsEmployee In Me
        On Error Resume Next
            colReturn.Add clsEmployee.CompLoc, clsEmployee.CompLoc
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next clsEmployee

    Set UniqueCompLoc = colReturn

End Property

Public Property Get FilterCompLoc(sCompLoc As String) As CEmployees

    Dim clsEmployee As CEmployee
    Dim clsReturn As CEmployees

    Set clsReturn = New CEmployees

    For Each clsEmployee In Me
        With clsEmployee
            If .CompLoc = sCompLoc Then
                clsReturn.Add clsEmployee
            End If
        End With
    Next clsEmployee

    Set FilterCompLoc = clsReturn


End Property

Public Property Get SalaryMatch() As Boolean

    Dim clsEmployee As CEmployee
    Dim dSalary As Double, dMaster As Double

    For Each clsEmployee In Me
        If clsEmployee.IsMaster Then
            dMaster = clsEmployee.Salary
        Else
            dSalary = dSalary + clsEmployee.Salary
        End If
    Next clsEmployee

    SalaryMatch = dMaster = dSalary

End Property

Public Property Get OutputToRange() As Variant

    Dim aReturn() As Variant
    Dim clsEmployee As CEmployee
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim aReturn(1 To Me.Count, 1 To 5)

    For Each clsEmployee In Me
        i = i + 1
        With clsEmployee
            aReturn(i, 1) = .Empid
            aReturn(i, 2) = .EmpName
            aReturn(i, 3) = .Salary
            aReturn(i, 4) = .Company
            aReturn(i, 5) = .Location
        End With
    Next clsEmployee

    OutputToRange = aReturn

End Property
```

Finally, add a Standard Module to your project and include this code.

```
Option Explicit

Public gclsEmployees As CEmployees

Sub CopyRanges()

    Dim clsEmployee As CEmployee
    Dim clsFiltered As CEmployees
    Dim colCompLoc As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rNext As Range
    Dim vaOutput As Variant

    Sheet2.UsedRange.ClearContents

    'Create a new CEmployees and fill it with CEmployee objects
    Set gclsEmployees = New CEmployees
    gclsEmployees.FillFromRange Sheet1.Range("A2:E11")

    'Get a list of unique company/location combinations
    Set colCompLoc = gclsEmployees.UniqueCompLoc

    'loop through the unique combinations
    For i = 1 To colCompLoc.Count
        'create a new CEmployees containing only that combination
        Set clsFiltered = gclsEmployees.FilterCompLoc(colCompLoc(i))
        'if the salaries add up to the master
        If clsFiltered.SalaryMatch Then
            'write the employee out to sheet2
            Set rNext = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            vaOutput = clsFiltered.OutputToRange
            rNext.Resize(UBound(vaOutput, 1), UBound(vaOutput, 2)).Value = vaOutput
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can see the example file I created at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1347353/FilterEmployees.xls

Comment: Thanks Dick,I done few changes in my original code and it is working.